# getting error message Enter a list of values(validation using django forms)

Tags: google-app-engine, django-forms

I am using `MultipleChoiceField` and already mentioned `required=False`. Then Why I am getting this error `Username:  Enter a list of values`.

```
def get_my_choices():
  users = User.query()
  choices_list = [(x.key.id(), x.email) for x in users]
  return choices_list

class MyForm(forms.Form):
  username = forms.MultipleChoiceField(required=False, choices=get_my_choices())
```

Am I doing something wrong? thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

You only want to return one choice, but you are using MultipleChoiceField.

If you change it to ChoiceField it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Implement a Widgetclass that knows how to fetch its data from the MultiValueDict:

```
class SelectMultiple(forms.widgets.SelectMultiple):
def value_from_datadict(self, data, files, name):
    try:
        return data.getall(name)
    except:
        return data.get(name, None)
```

and pass this to the Fields constructor: MultipleChoiceField(widget=SelectMultiple)

Use item_type=unicode for the field.

field = db.ListProperty(item_type=unicode, choices=...)

Source :http://vanderwijk.info/blog/google-app-engine-django-and-multiplechoicefield/